# GHC anything results in "ld: library not found for -lgmp"

Tags: haskell, osx-yosemite, ghc, osx-elcapitan

I'm trying to compile haskell programs on my mac running OS X 10.10 Yosemite, but ghc fails every time with ***ld: library not found for -lgmp***:

```
$ ghc foo.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( foo.hs, foo.o )
Linking foo ...
ld: library not found for -lgmp
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Help?

Comment: Use this http://ghcformacosx.github.io/

Comment: @eccstartup Do you mean that you used this for that tool? If so, that's great, glad I could help. If you're promoting it, that's cool too. Though I didn't specifically mention it, if I recall correctly (and how I prefer to install software on macs) I had installed ghc with brew.

Comment: I mean, when I used the `homebrew` version of ghc, it got this error. But things get right when I switch to the `possible official` one in that link.

Comment: Cool. It doesn't feel official to me, although its site is really well done. If I get confirmation of officialness, I'll add that to my answer below. As is, I stand by my point that I don't like to install random programs via their own distribution systems and would prefer to use packages from homebrew.

Comment: Yeah, you decide what is right. Do you remember when ghc7.8.4 released, there was no ghc7.8.4 but only ghc7.8.3 on that site? It took long before the confirmation of that update. So I guess it is `possible official`. You can ask `ghc-devs` mailing list. Whatever, you decide. I just solved this issue with that `ghc`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The missing thing on my system was up to date command line tools from xcode. Installing the most recent version with `xcode-select --install` fixed the problem.

Comment: Fixes perfectly (after upgrading to El Captain). Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

I did `brew uninstall ghc && brew install ghc` and it fixed it (on Yosemite).

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on OSX (10.15) Catalina:

```
brew install pkg-config hidapi libev gmp
```